# Issues with decoding json object

Tags: php, html, json

Thanks for your time in reading this post.

My php file is receiving a json object.  But I am facing issues while decoding it.

My php code:

```
$data=$_POST['arg1']; 
echo $data;
$json = json_decode($data,true);
echo $json;
$i = 1;
foreach($json as $key => $value) {
    print "<h3>Name".$i." : " . $value . "</h3>";
    $i++;
}
```

When I `echo` data results as below.

```
{
    "SCI-2": {
        "quantity": 2,
        "id": "SCI-2",
        "price": 280,
        "cid": "ARTCOTSB"
    }
}
```

When I echo `$json`, result is as it follows :

> Array
>   Name1 : Array.

Please assist as i need tho access the `cid` and `quantity` values in the `$data`.

Comment: You get a single object in json? Also, does it always have this format?

Comment: @SimplyMe : Thanks for your reply.  No it's not always one object.  It can be multiple too.(checkout products in shopping cart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_decode` returns an array. And to print array you can use `print_r` or `var_dump`.

Now to access your values you can try :

`$json["SCI-2"]["quantity"]` for quantity and `$json["SCI-2"]["cid"]` for cid.

Demo : https://eval.in/522350

To access in `foreach` you need this :

```
foreach($json as $k) {
   foreach($k as $key => $value) {
      print "<h3>Name".$i." : " . $value . "</h3>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks : but there is possibility that i will get multiple products as well example format : {"SCI-2":{"quantity":3,"id":"SCI-2","price":280,"cid":"ARTCOTSB"},"SCI-3":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-3","price":480,"cid":"ARTPUR 002"},"SCI-4":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-4","price":600,"cid":"ARTMSKBUD"}}.  How can i dynamically access the values then

Comment: Thank you so much you really helped me a lot.

Comment: Hi, I need to store CID and QUANTITY values in separate php variables $cid and $quantity rather than printing.  Please help me out

Comment: But how would you like to use it? Because it's in loop.

Comment: Basically this checkout page. Based on cid i will fetch name image price from database and display to the user along with the quantity

Comment: Then store your cid in array and after loop you need to use `implode` on it. With implode you will get comma separated string which you can use with `in` condition in database.

Comment: cid already coming as key in the json object.  Can you please share me the syntax as i dont have such expertise on what you are saying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104053/discussion-between-user3762051-and-mr-engineer).

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not know the number of items in your object, use this:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

After this, iterate the `$obj` variable and **after** that, inside the loop, use the foreach to get each property.

```
foreach($iteratedObject as $key => $value) {
    //your stuff
}
```